# Unable to pass flow through custom stages with "Flow.through_specs/3"

Tags: elixir, genstage

I'm trying to include a GenStage in a Flow pipeline. However, this results in an exception being raised. If I understand correctly, `Flow.through_specs/3` will spawn a number of stages and partition incoming items accordingly. Am I missing something? I use Flow v0.14.2.

The exception:

```
{:down, {%ArgumentError{message: "the :partition option is required when subscribing to a producer with partition dispatcher"}, [{GenStage.PartitionDispatcher, :subscribe, 3, [file: 'lib/gen_stage/dispatchers/partition_dispatcher.ex', line: 143]}, {GenStage, :dispatcher_callback, 3, [file: 'lib/gen_stage.ex', line: 2160]}, {:gen_server, :try_dispatch, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 637]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 711]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}
Last message: {:DOWN, #Reference<0.1791475268.948436996.112315>, :process, #PID<0.183.0>, {:down, {%ArgumentError{message: "the :partition option is required when subscribing to a producer with partition dispatcher"}, [{GenStage.PartitionDispatcher, :subscribe, 3, [file: 'lib/gen_stage/dispatchers/partition_dispatcher.ex', line: 143]}, {GenStage, :dispatcher_callback, 3, [file: 'lib/gen_stage.ex', line: 2160]}, {:gen_server, :try_dispatch, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 637]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 711]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}}
State: {%{}, %{done?: true, producers: %{}, trigger: #Function<2.13930487/3 in Flow.Window.Global.materialize/5>}, {1, 6}, [], #Function<42.60253262/4 in Flow.Materialize.mapper_ops/1>}
```

Here's the pipeline:

```
specs = [
  {
    {PBFParser.Decompressor, []},
    []
  }
]

PBFParser.Reader.stream("test.osm.pbf")
    |> Stream.drop(1)
    |> Stream.take(1_000)
    |> Flow.from_enumerable(max_demand: 100)
    |> Flow.through_specs(specs, max_demand: 5, stages: 6)
    |> Flow.partition(max_demand: 5, stages: 12)
    |> Flow.map(&PBFParser.Decoder.decode_block/1)
    |> Flow.partition(window: Flow.Window.count(20))
    |> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end, fn batch, total ->
      [batch | total]
    end)
    |> Flow.emit(:state)
    |> Flow.partition(max_demand: 20, stages: 2)
    |> Flow.each(fn item -> IO.inspect(length(item)) end)
    |> Flow.run()
```

The GenStage:

```
defmodule PBFParser.Decompressor do
  use GenStage

  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, opts)
  end

  def init(_) do
    {:producer_consumer, :zlib.open()}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, z) do
    ...
    {:noreply, result, z}
  end
end
```

Comment: I’m wondering if you ever found a solution to this problem. I’m hitting the same thing when I have `Flow.partition` after `Flow.through_specs`. I see the comment below but I’m not clear on which consumer needs the partition option.

Comment: Answering my own follow up, it is complaining about the `Flow.partition` _before_ the `Flow.through_specs`. Your `specs` would need to be passed the `partition` option, or the `Flow.partition` would need to be setup with `dispatcher: GenStage.DemandDispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer is subscribing to [`GenStage.PartitionDispatcher`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.PartitionDispatcher.html#content) that is the default one for [`Flow.partition/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html#partition/2-options).

You declare two partitions (with `stages: 2`) option.

Hence your consumer should have `partition: ...` options passed as [shown here](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.PartitionDispatcher.html#module-examples).